# Drop down menu not working in desktop browsers although it works in Android. What is the CSS tag for such option?

Tags: javascript, android, html

in the next code the dropdown menu is not recognised by the desktop browser (Chrome 81.0.4044.138 and Firefox 75.0) and I've tried everything (or rather everything, since it is not working). The strange thing is that the same code  works perfect in Android. Are there any tips I should keep in mind when writing code for both desktop browsers and Android ? I would appreciate even the slightest idea you may have. Thank you all in advance. (PS) I have a picture for you. When mouse is pressed over the three dots they become red but the submenu with "Option 3" and "Option 4" does not appear, as it does here in snippet.

[image]

```css
.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 7;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a id="Option 1">Option 1</a>
  <a id="Option 2">Option 2</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">...</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a id="Option 3">Option 3</a>
      <a id="Option 4">Option 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what is not working but I got working results for FF and Chrome desktop on Windows. What I see is that you change your appearance on hover. Which works fine for mouse-based navigation but would not work on mobile browsers because of the `:hover`. On touch only devices you would not be able to hover something (or at least not very convenient and user friendly).

Comment: If I'm getting something wrong, please clarify the current behaviour and what you would expect.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me in Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit), so the problem must be with your browser or development environment. Try using safe mode for your browser

Comment: @Masoud. Ok then since it is working for you, I shall check it more. Thank you a lot.